# Calling a script from another doesn't work

Tags: php

I'm trying to call a second php script from my main script, but I can't get it working.

In my main script I'm creating an array, add items to it and start a session to pass the array data over to the second script:

```
    $sorted[] = {.....some data....};
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["$myarray"] = $sorted;
    echo 'starting second script';
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'second_script.php');
```

With the second script I'm trying to display the array

```
    echo 'running second script';
    session_start();
    foreach ($_SESSION["$myarray"] as $vals){
      ....display array contents...
    }
```

If I run the second script directly it returns "running second script", followed by a warning "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()", which is expected as there hasn't been started a session, but at least it's doing something.

Why doesn't calling from the main script not work?

Comment: When using include or require, it's easier to think about your scripts as one big/long script. Just as if you had actually put all code in one file. No need to pass variables and similar.

Comment: Pretty certain `session_start();` has to be the first thing on the page.

Comment: does `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'second_script.php'` result reflect to the intended file? it's a bit weird for referring the path using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.. because it returns the current executing file path..

Comment: remove `session_start();` from second script

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($_SESSION["$myarray"])`?

Comment: @Lars: var_dump($_SESSION["$myarray"]  in the first script returns the data as expected, but from the second nothing happens.

Comment: @Bagus: if I remove "$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']" the second script can't be found. As a result of that it doesn't finish the first script either

Comment: well @HB1963, i did not suggest you to remove it.. just check what is the output.. and see whether the path is correct or not - cause you did not include your project structure for reference to help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some comments already suggested: session_start() should be the first statement, but you don't need it. Also you don't need the superglobal $_SESSION.

This will work, first script:

```
$sorted = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
    echo 'starting second script <br>';
    include('second_script.php');
```

second script:

```
   echo 'running second script <br>';
foreach ($sorted as $vals){
  echo $vals;
}
```

Comment: This sample script is tested live and works well. Please post the whole script that you tried.

Comment: I've got it working!! When cleaning up the script in order to post it miraculous starts to work. Thx C.A.